# ArcGIS Python API: does the target server know if the script was launched from Windows admin account?

Tags: python, powershell, arcgis-server

I wrote a Python script which basically connects to an ArcGIS Enterprise server and checks Items' dependencies.

The script uses built-in admin account credentials of the ArcGIS system. There are no other credentials involved in the code.

The script is stored on a remote Windows server.

I connect to the server as an admin, open Powershell terminal in non-admin mode (execution policy is Bypass) and run the script. It works fine.

Other user connects to to the server as non-admin, opens Powershell terminal in non-admin mode (execution policy is Bypass) and runs the script. He gets error from ArcGIS Enterprise server: `"Error 403. Exception: you do not have permissions to access this resource or perform this operation".`

I already ruled out the possibility that there are some local permissions issues on the Windows server and also quadruple-checked that the user Roles and Permissions are correct in ArcGIS.

My question is: when i connect to the remote Windows server via RDP as an admin and launch a Python script via Powershell terminal in non-dmin mode, can the target server (in my case the ArcGIS server) somehow be aware that the script was launched from an administrative Windows account?

Comment: Absolutely.  A remote connection on windows passes the user info from the client to the server.  A controller in c# uses the credentials (see : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/overview/understanding-models-views-and-controllers-cs).  Also when you have a server with a Frontend and Backend the Frontend credentials are passed to the Backend Database.